# VBA generate characters A B C D

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have Column C in Excel filled number sorted in ascending order.
I want to write in Column B,  this number in another format

For example  I that is what I need to get but have no clue of how I can do it

```
ColumB  ColumC    
0001-A     1
0001-B     1
0002-A     2
0002-B     2
0002-C     2
```

To have `0001-` I use `Format(Cells(c,3),"0000") & "-"`
But I struggle to populate the `A B C D` etc.. for every row

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Macro3()
Dim cl As Range
myinteger = 64
currentinteger = 0
currentvalue = Range("C1").Value

For Each cl In Range("C1:C5")

    If cl.Value <> currentvalue Then
        currentinteger = 1
        currentvalue = cl.Value
    Else
        currentinteger = currentinteger + 1
    End If

    cl.Offset(0, -1).Value = Format(cl.Value, "0000") & "-" & Chr(myinteger + currentinteger)


Next cl

End Sub
```

Comment: Genius that works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula in B1 copied down:

**=TEXT(C1,"0000")&"-"&LEFT(ADDRESS(1,COUNTIF(C$1:C1,C1),4,1),1)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub main()

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim flagSame As Boolean


For i = 1 To 5500

    flagSame = True
    j = 1
    While flagSame = True
        Cells(i + j - 1, 2) = "000" + Strings.Trim(Str(Cells(i + j - 1, 3))) + "-" + Strings.Trim(Chr(j + 64))
        If Cells(i + j, 3) <> Cells(i + j - 1, 3) Then
            flagSame = False
            i = i + j - 1
        Else
            j = j + 1
        End If

    Wend

Next i


End Sub
```

[image]

Also here is an article I've written regarding string processing on my blog, it might help [Excel VBA String Processing and Manipulation](http://software-solutions-online.com/2014/02/11/2/)

Comment: I don't like hard-coded solutions plus it enters the 4th character as `0` which doesn't match what OP requested.

Comment: what do you mean by hard-coded?:)

Comment: This looks OK... but I want to go far more than 2... my column goes to 5500... and the only way to recognize duplicates is with letters A B C D etcc

Comment: Whats the pattern for A B C D? Could you provide more rows

Comment: Let says for the number 15 i have it 8 times in Column C... So in column B I need `0015-A` in front of the 1st `15` then `0015-B` in front of the 2nd `15`.....until `0015-H` in front of the last `15`

Comment: please try the new code